# foundation 6 orbit start autoplay on element click

Tags: javascript, jquery, zurb-foundation

I don't seem to find the controls for this, like for instance with reveal modals, where I can give any element the data-reveal.
What I'm trying to achieve is loading the page without autoplay, then setting the play of orbit on a button.
So far I tried to trick it using data-autoplay=true/false and data-timer-delay= really high/ 2000

```
$('#startOrbit').click(function(){

    $('.orbit').attr('data-timer-delay',2000);
  });
```

so the attr goes in but the orbit does not start...
what combinations of options can I use?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a codepen example ([link](http://codepen.io/MKallivokas/pen/EyGKGP)) with an orbit sample slider and the functionality that you want to achieve.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elem = new Foundation.Orbit($('.orbit'), {'autoPlay': false});

    $('#startOrbit').on('click', function() {
        elem.options.autoPlay = true;
        elem.options.timerDelay = 2000;
        $('.orbit').foundation('geoSync');
    });
});
```

Firstly, i initialize the orbit slider with the auto play option set to false.
Then i attach a click event listener on the button element with the #startOrbit id, change the two options and finally call the geoSync method that sets a timer object on the orbit and starts the counter for the next slide.

Comment: Thanks, in the meantime the requirements changed for this task... I'm sure it works and I'll try it asap, I will definately need this in the future